# Non uniform, multivariable time series in R.

Tags: r, time-series

A fraction of my dataset is:

```
 > df
   v1 v2 v3         v4
 1  1  0  1 03-11-2013
 2  5  2  0 09-11-2013
 3  4  2  0 12-11-2013
 4  2  6  1 14-11-2013
 5  3  0  1 21-11-2013
 6  0  0  1 24-11-2013
```

where v4 are non-uniform dates (the real data is significantly larger). The aim is to estimate the next value of "v1" (observation number 7 in this very reduced dataset) based on the pre-exisitng information. The easiest would be perhaps using only previous values of v1, but v1, v2 and v3 are potentially related. Therefore, the ideal situation would be utilising all information.

I tried the package forecast() in R but I find difficulties to deal with non-uniform time series. I also came accross the arima() function/models, but yet again it seems will only work with uniform time series(?). Therefore, the question would be:

How can I predict the value of a certain variable based on non-uniform, historical information of multiple variables (including the one I want to predict) in R?

Comment: Convert your dates to numeric, do a fit of `v1 = f(datevalue)` for the linear or nonlinear function of your choice, and plug in the new datevalues for which you wish to predict `v1` . Note that extrapolation of a nonlinear dataset is very risky.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Carl. But if I am not wrong, your technique would still not allow me to include all, v1,v2,v3...in the model, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolate your data and try a vector autoregressive model or disregard v2 and v3 and just predict v1 from its (interpolated) history.  The authors of both packages have books for more info.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF, index = 4, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
g <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "day")) # grid
zz <- na.spline(merge(z, g))

# alternative 1. forcast all variables for next 10 days
library(vars)
fm <- VAR(zz)
predict(fm) # AR prediction of next 10 days

# alternative 2. univariate forecast disregarding v2 and v3
library(forecast)
forecast(zz$v1)
```